# Issues with query using Having clause in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm having some problems getting a query to run in MS Access 2007. I have the following query that works fine:

```
  SELECT boq.PIPE_AG, 
         boq.PIPE_UG, 
         boq.Pipe, 
         boq.Unit, 
         SUM(boq.Quantity) AS SumOfQuantity
    FROM [Total - BOQ] boq
GROUP BY boq.PIPE_AG, boq.PIPE_UG, boq.Pipe, boq.Unit
  HAVING boq.PIPE_AG In (-1,1) OR boq.PIPE_UG In (-1,1);
```

When I add **boq.Pipe ='1'** to the `HAVING` caluse like this:

```
HAVING boq.Pipe ='1' AND (boq.PIPE_AG In (-1,1) OR boq.PIPE_UG In (-1,1))
```

I get an error that says:

> You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'boq.Pipe='1' And (boq.PIPE_AG In (-1,1) Or boq.PIPE_UG In (-1,1))' as part of an aggregate function.

I'm a bit perplexed as to why it's complaining. I do have all three fileds in the `GROUP BY` clause of my query. The query works fine if I change it up to use a `WHERE` clause, but I'm trying to understand why it's complaining when I add the Pipe field to the `HAVING` clause.

Comment: Use WHERE clause instead of HAVING. You should  use HAVING only with aggregate functions. For example you could use HAVING Sum(boq.Quantity) > 1000 that should do it.

Comment: @THEn: Should be the answer -- I'd upvote if you do post it as one

Comment: I know it'll work using where, I'm just trying to figure out why adding the pipe=1 causes it to fail. The pipe_ag and pipe_ug aren't aggregate functions either.

Comment: Please see http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/having.php http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sqlhaving.html http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx

Comment: If you were not using an aggregate function in your query (Sum in this case) you could get away with not having an aggregate function in the having clause.

Comment: @Jeff O But the first query does have a aggregate function in the query and no aggregate function in the having clause and it does work. It's just when I add the pipe field that it fails.

Comment: @xecaps12: The error does seem strange, given all the circumstances. Are you positive that you haven't omitted `boq.Pipe` from your actual query's GROUP BY? Another guess (very wild and weird one) is, maybe Access would like the columns in the HAVING clause to appear in the same order as they are mentioned in GROUP BY?

Comment: @Andriy I thought about the order thing also and tired it and it didn't work. I think it was due to the fact my filed was a calculated field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of MS Access do you use? I just replicated your exact table/query in my copy of Access 2007 and it worked perfectly fine (as expected). I assumed all your columns to be of Number type (long) and Pipe column to be of Text

Comment: Access 2007, and the table `total - boq` is actually a query, but the data types are as you mentioned.

Comment: It does work when I make a table from my query. Not sure what that tells me, but it's a step forward I guess.

Comment: Sorry, man. It works either table or query in my Access. Try to re-create the query.

Comment: After some testing, I found that it's because the Pipe column is a calculated column in my query. I tried creating some simple columns in the query `columnTest: "A"` then added the `columnTest="A"` to the having clause it failed. Apparently it seems that it's calculated columns that can't be used in the having clause.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it lead me to what I'm pretty sure was the the issue.

Comment: @xecaps12: Isn't it... er, curious? You are allowed to group by a calculated column but are not allowed to use it in HAVING. Still, it's just MS Access...

Comment: @xecaps12 Thanks! I voted up your question because your resolution will serve me in the future

Answer (score 5):

Use WHERE clause instead of HAVING. You should use HAVING only with aggregate functions. 
For example you could use

```
HAVING Sum(boq.Quantity) > 1000
```

that should do it

Comment: I guess you meant _HAVING can be used with GROUP BY_ (not just aggregate functions). One can use HAVING on grouped by columns